# Function to convert Dictionary to Image works for an image but not for an image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, dictionary

I have written a small function that first takes an image, calculates mean for each of its bands and then converts the dictionary of the mean value to an image with each mean value acting as a new band to the image.

When I applied this function to one image, it worked. However, when I mapped this function to an image collection, it shows an error.

[image]

I didn't quite understand what the error mean. Also, I think the function is actually being executed in the image collection as well because when I print the results, I don't get any error. The error occurs when I try to add the result as a layer.

The link to the code is below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b0279b87c668347dccae455b4e42974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you what's going on: `band B10 might require an explicit cast` but don't cast just that band because it will throw the same error for the next, and so on. Cast all bands.

```js
var meanref = function (image){
  var meanDictionary = (image.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: image.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}));
  // Cast all bands of the result to be of Integer type
  return  meanDictionary.toImage().updateMask(image.select('B11')).toInt();
};
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c3f744e390a29296108ba16b70e30cb3